# Entity Framework One to Many Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[image: One to Many relationship]

I have this model.

**Rule.**

A Company can have multiple service

**The Problem**

User can enter a list of service name(list of string) and then can retrieve a company which has that list of service.

**Question**

How can i do this? The first solution that comes to my mind is to join the table first and then use the lambda expression from the joined table. Any other solution?

Comment: Can you provide some code samples of what you've tried and what hasn't worked?

Comment: How company is retrieve on basis of service name, I mean all services need to match the condition or one of service enter by user match condition?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar what do you mean? This is the example of a case. If i input Transportation and Electrical. The input will be converted to list of string contain of these two words then the system will do the query

Comment: @donthurtme Then follow [Andrey Molotkov answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32132468/2106315)  below!

Comment: can't you just query service table and get the company name Service.where(s => s.Service_Name == "myservice")

Comment: For now i'm using full join as my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Where()`:

```
Companies.Where(c => requiredServices.All(s => c.Services.Contains(s)))
```

If `List<string>` is used then:

```
Companies.Where(company => serviceNames.All(
    serviceName => company.Services.Any(service => service.Service_Name == serviceName)))
```

Comment: yeah this can be done if the requiredServices is  a list of services. My problem is that the input is actually just the name (string type). Any idea?

Comment: @donthurtme you can assume `requiredServices` to be of type `List<string>`. *(and same way for `c.services`)*.  got idea now?